# If you didn't do this, you should be worried

Tags: discussion, email

The password change email has

> The password to your Stack Exchange account has been changed.
>
> (If you didn't do this, you should be worried.)

It's funny, but is it appropriate for users of non-technology sites on the Stack Exchange network such as English Language & Usage?

For the benefit of such users, there should be explicit instructions on what to do if their account has been hijacked.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @DonaldDuck I've edited my question to explain.

Answer (score 10):

It's actually quite serious - it means that your Stack Exchange password (and other things) have been compromised, and you really *should* be worried. You might also need to do other things to regain control of your account, and check for password reuse.

As such, getting that email without changing your password is roughly as serious as contracting a case of the black death.

I suppose adding in information on what to do on a account compromise would be *nice*, but do we want to scare the muggles that much?

Comment: I want to upvote you except for your equating an account takeover with certain death, which is sending mixed messages to a person who thinks SE takes account takeovers too seriously.

Comment: I'm pretty sure bubonic plague is treatable these days. Much like a compromised password

Comment: Ok, so if I offered you a Sophie's choice of having your SE account compromised or contacting the plague, you wouldn't feel strongly one way or another?

Comment: I'd rather know I had either rather than not know. Unlike the dark ages, we have proper medical care.

Comment: That's sidestepping my question. Your equation of the two in your answer is misplaced. But I won't bother you any more about it. It's your answer, not mine.

Comment: `...Unlike the dark ages, we have proper medical care` You clearly don't live in the US. ;)

Comment: I think giving specific instructions is less scary, rather than more scary.